# C - linked list queue; front always equal rear

Tags: c, queue

I'm trying to implement a queue in C using a linked list that stores void pointers. I'm having a problem with the insert function; front always equals rear after an insert (testing with ints). I'm having trouble pin-pointing the problem.

```
typedef struct node{
    void *data;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

typedef struct queueStruct{
    struct node *front, *rear;
} queueStruct;

typedef struct queueStruct *QueueADT;

QueueADT que_create( ){
    QueueADT queue;
    queue = (QueueADT) malloc(sizeof(queueStruct));
    if(queue != NULL){
        queue->front = queue->rear = NULL;
    }
    else{
        printf("Insufficient memory for new queue.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return queue;
}

void que_insert( QueueADT queue, void *data ){

    Node *newNode;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if(queue->front == NULL){
        queue->front = queue->rear = newNode;
    }
    else{
        queue->rear->next = newNode;
        queue->rear = newNode;
    }
    printf("%i\t%i\n",  *((int *) queue->front->data),  *((int *)queue->rear->data) );
}
int main(void){
    QueueADT test;
    test = que_create();
    for(int i=0; i<9; ++i) {
         que_insert(test, (void *) &i);
   }
}
```

Comment: How are you allocating the data you are sending to `que_insert`?

Comment: Do you initialize `*front` with `NULL` somewhere?

Comment: Obviously on the *first* call to `que_insert`, `front` will equal `rear`.

Comment: But you check for `== NULL` before...

Comment: I added my create and main function. I know front = rear on first call, but this is the case for every insert i do afterwards.

Comment: In your `main()` you always hand over the address of `i`. So you are not adding different values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

```
int main(void)
{
  int a =1, b=2, c=3;
  struct queueStruct queue = {0};
  que_insert( &queue, &a);
  que_insert( &queue, &b);
  que_insert( &queue, &c);
}
```

I get:

```
> ./q
1       1
1       2
1       3
```

Seems that it works to me.  Than again, you didn't post your driver code.  If you are doing something like:

```
int main(void)
{
  int a=1;
  struct queueStruct queue = {0};
  que_insert( &queue, &a);
  a=2;
  que_insert( &queue, &a);
}
```

Then it will always be the same, because both nodes point to the same address in memory, so when you change a to 2, both node's pointers point to the same memory and therefore are changed at the same time.  Most likely, this is your real problem.

Comment: You changed your example to be more fully defined while I was replying... and you did indeed use the same address for all nodes... the &i means that all nodes point to the same address, so when you increment i you increment i in ALL the nodes.

Comment: Doh. It was as you said. I completely overlooked that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the data you're putting into the queue. You've got a local variable, `i`, and you provide `&i` for everything -- so all the elements in your queue are the same element (whose value changes as you run through your loop).

You need to make discrete objects to put in your queue!

```
for(int i=0; i<9; ++i) {
    int *object = malloc(sizeof(*object);
    *object = i;
    que_insert(test, (void *) object);
}
```

Doing this, you'll need to remember to `free(...)` your objects once you're done with them.

Comment: No need for the malloc. He just needs to pass in `(void *) i` instead of `(void *) &i`. After all, he's just using integers for test values anyway. They don't actually have to be valid pointers.